# Switch Two Language In Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

Now I am Working on a Wordpress Project. and my problem is in my project site must work in two language [image: Looks Like this] Like this If i select one of this language site Must Change the language as i select please help me to find a solution :'( (I wont need a plugin because its not change it proper )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you don't need a plugin, but [WPML](http://wpml.org/) is cheap and the best at doing this, by far. I have used it personally doing client work and it is the best multi-language plugin for WordPress I've used.

Comment: Oh so it can translate language Proper ??

Comment: You can pay for translations through an associated service, but otherwise you will have to do the translations yourself. Essentially, for every piece of content there are two or more translations, which you can enter in via a tab on the post.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [**gtranslate plugin**](http://gtranslate.net/features) only and it is working very well. It has Translations between 58 languages with the support of flags.

In the settings panel of this plugin, put translation "on fly". Then it will not reload the page for translation.

Just Try it. Cheers!!!